# PivotTable Fields Range References

Tags: model, pivot, range, excel-2013

I have a question concerning pivot tables added to the data model in Excel 2013.

Somehow I managed that one (PivotTable fields) range refers to three different tables in three different worksheets of the same workbook. But I don’t know anymore how I came to this result.

All other attempts produced ranges that refer to only one table.

I have been looking for seven hours in the internet and in my Excel books. And didn’t find any answer.

Can you explain to me how I produce a range that refers to three different tables in three different worksheets?

Comment: happened by accident :( no purpose

Answer (score 0):

Although conventional to pivot data from a single source Excel does offer the option of [Multiple consolidation ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-report-HA010226585.aspx), though the data layout of each needs to be similar.